# dsolve. numeric. to know which method Maple used

Tags: numeric, maple, dsolve

How would I know that dsolve numeric used which method to solve my non-linear bvp. Is there a way to find out about the method used by Maple 2019.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb SO's recommendations addressed to new users (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour); then do read what's on-topic here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)